# Should we handle reuse-code app after updates?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Recently, Azure AD apps made some updates:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#october-2018

> Authorization codes can no longer be reused.

My question is should we handle with authorized resource which previously reused the code to get refresh token?

For example, I used the same code to auth https://api.office.com/discovery/

and onedrive resources, should those refresh tokens needed to be re-auth or something?

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already obtained the refresh tokens previously, you do not need to obtain new ones. You only need to ensure any code you have that would attempt to re-use an authorization code does not do this anymore.